# WSO2 Identity Server and WSO2 API Manager integration - java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9999;

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have integrated WSO2 Identity server and WSO2 API Manager.
While starting the WSO2 Id Server , I am getting the below error in console..

```
 ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager} -  Could not create the RMI local registry
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9999; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:341)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:249)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
        at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:208)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:152)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:137)
```

Can anyone help?

But its starting successfully with the following message

```
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Server           :  WSO2 Identity Server-5.2.0
[2016-12-27 15:31:13,744]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  WSO2 Carbon started in 57 sec
[2016-12-27 15:31:14,909]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://localhost:9443/carbon/
[2016-12-27 15:31:14,948]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.x509Certificate.internal.X509CertificateServiceComponent} -  X509 Certificate Servlet activated successfully..
```

Before i started wso2server.bat , there is nothing in the port..

Comment: check whether there's anything listening on that port, lsof -i :9999 on linux shows a list of processes listening on that port4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My machine's JAVA_OPTS was being set to debug mode and this was causing WSO2 to start in debug mode . Thus it was listening to 9999 port.
I have removed the JAVA_OPTS and now able to start it properly.

related issue
[WSO2 Identity Server listening to port 9999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350196/wso2-identity-server-listening-to-port-9999?noredirect=1#comment69913357_41350196)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this is having another WSO2 instance running, which is utilizing specific ports.

1st you must check, which wso2 instances (jvm) are running using this command. (in Linux/MacOS)

```
ps -ef|grep java


Sample Output:

502  8166  8151   0  5:04PM ttys003    1:41.74 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/Users/sahanmarasinghe/Documents/SOFTWARE/wso2am-4.2.0/repository/logs/heap-dump.hprof -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -classpath......
```

Then you must kill any already running instances.

Kill this instance using the processor id. (PID)

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Ex:

```
kill -9 8166
```

One of the key reason for having another WSO2 instance running is not stopping the WSO2 server instance properly.

Further in Linux/MacOS, starting the WSO2 products without proper permission also can cause this issues.

To resolve this you should provide the proper permissions before start the WSO2 instance as follows:

i). Change the ownership to your user name:

```
sudo chown -R <PC_USER> <WSO2_PRODUCT_FOLDER_PATH>
```

Ex:

```
sudo chown -R user1 /Library/WSO2/wso2am-4.2.0
```

ii). Change the user permission to execute the files:

```
sudo chmod +x <WSO2_PRODUCT_FOLDER_PATH>/bin/*.sh
```

Ex:

```
sudo chmod +x /Library/WSO2/wso2am-4.2.0/bin/*.sh
```

iii). Now you can start the WSO2 product.