# WSO2 Identity Server listening to port 9999

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

[image]

When ever WSO2 ID Server or WSO2 API Manager starts , it always listens to port 9999.. How can i change this port to some other port?

I have tried editing carbon.xml RMIRegistryPort .But no luck..Its still listening to port 9999..

Comment: did you edit wso2server.bat file,  " listening for transport dt_socket at address" message will get printed when server is stared in debug mode

Comment: No..I have not edited.Which portion should i check?
Because of this I am unable to run API Manager and ID Server in the same machine..

Comment: check JAVA_OPTS , it might have been set in system level so all application will get affected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369522/set-default-heap-size-in-windows

JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=%DEBUG_PORT%

Comment: Perfect!... it was system level settings...it worked now..

Comment: great... I have added the findings as answer, accept the correct answer so it will help  other users who face same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"listening for transport dt_socket at address" message will get printed when server is stared in debug mode.

check JAVA_OPTS , debug option[1] might have been set in system level so all application will get affected [2]

[1]
JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=%DE‌​BUG_PORT%

[2] [Set default heap size in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369522/set-default-heap-size-in-windows)